# Connecting two docker containers and then return result with restful API

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have one container with install ubuntu on that and then install openmodelica for the main container and then have another container that has restful API with python and then I want to run the second container and then connect it with the first one and run openmodelica and then return a result(with CSV file) to first one.

how could I implement it?

Comment: I believe you can reach it by `docker-compose`. Have you tried it?

Comment: You have multiple questions packages in one question. You need to decide what is your approach toward implementation, start the implementing it and when you have a concrete question for which you can not find answer on SO, create your question and provide examples that can be reproduced. Here is not clear what is your question. Do you have issue with packaging openmodelica, creating API, connectivity, deployment, etc.

Comment: @Saeed not yet.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski I think my question is clear, just I have an issue connecting those containers to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` files. Add required contents and lines, then run containers with this command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

You can read more about them at [Docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Regarding `return a result(with CSV file) to first one`, you should ask another question as you're asking multiple questions.